# An inequality for positive operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $S$ and $T$ be positive operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose that $S \le T$. Since the square root function is operator monotone, it follows that $S^{1/2} \le T^{1/2}$. Does the inequality

$$S^{1/2}RS^{1/2} \le T^{1/2}RT^{1/2}$$

hold for all positive operators $R$?

Comment: I guess it doesn't. Here's a motivation why this might be wrong (it is not a proof though!!). Suppose: $S\leq T\implies SR\leq TR$ $(R\geq0)$ Then also: $S\leq T\implies S^2\leq ST\leq T^2$ But that is wrong!

Comment: Try to find an example with square matrices in Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easy example on dimension 2. Let
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2\\1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix},\ T=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, \ R=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then $S^{1/2}=S$, $T^{1/2}=T$, and $S^{1/2}\leq T^{1/2}$. But 
$$
S^{1/2}RS^{1/2}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2\\1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix},\ \ T^{1/2}RT^{1/2}=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},
$$
which are not comparable.